# Accessing Browser Favorites (WinForms/C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, favorites

Where and how can I access web browser Favorites and history?

Is it the same place for all browsers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a small code to get the history for IE :

```
    public List<string> PopulateUrlList()
{
    string regKey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\TypedURLs";
    RegistryKey subKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(regKey);
    string url = null;
    List<string> urlList = new List<string>();
    int counter = 1;
    while (true) {
        string sValName = "url" + counter.ToString();
        url = (string)subKey.GetValue(sValName);
        if ((object)url == null) {
            break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit While
        }
        urlList.Add(url);
        counter += 1;
    }
    return urlList;
}
```

Comment: :O - Perfect! Thanks so much for that :D I was expecting a link or two, but you just made my day :D